# Spring + IBM WebSphere context fail

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, websphere

Trying to deploy a Spring Boot application to a WebSphere environment.

Have deployed to Tomcat and TomEE without issue.

Getting the following error in WebSphere:

> [30/11/15 15:04:17:329 GMT] 0000000c SystemOut     O 2015-11-30
>   15:04:17,328 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]
>   -  [30/11/15 15:04:17:337 GMT] 0000000c SystemOut     O 2015-11-30 15:04:17,333
>   ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] -  java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   WebApplicationContext found: initializer not registered?  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.findWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:593)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:363)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1844)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:1051)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:972)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:651)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:453)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:304)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:732)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:617)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1146)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:611)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:759)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$3.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2074)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5395)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5483)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2079)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:332)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:899)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:496)
>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.my.Application</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**EDIT**

The Application annotations are:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(this.getClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Websphere and tomcat are you using ?

Comment: WebSphere 7 & Tomcat 6

Comment: The stacktrace shows that Spring couldn't find web context. Please check your configuration annotations first. Also in order to support Spring Boot on WebSphere you probably should use - spring-boot-legacy. The following commit containt an application sample -  https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy/commit/52655b948dae560e887c22bc442d94c778c0beb0. I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @AntonNovopashin we are using legacy. Have added code and configurations which I believe are correct?

Comment: @timothyclifford I think it is annotation order or something similar. Here is the link to an example for legacy project - https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy/blob/master/spring-boot-sample-secure-legacy/src/main/java/demo/Application.java. In the boot documentation `SpringBootServletInitializer` comes with the `SpringBootApplication` annotation.